# how to unsubscribe of function in method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-material, dialog

Working on dialog component with angular js and now I find out that my function is subscribed and in if condition do not quit method, but continuously executing another function `afterClosed()` , here is example of code :

```
openCreateNewContentDialog(): void {
    const oldData = this.dataSource.data;
    const dialogConfig = AppConstants.matDialogConfig();
    const dialog = this.dialog.open(LicenseDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialog.beforeClosed().subscribe(licenceDate => {
      for (const datesToCheck of oldData) {
        const newDateFrom = new Date(licenceDate.expirationDateFrom);
        const oldDateTo = new Date(datesToCheck.expirationDateTo.toString());
        if (newDateFrom <= oldDateTo) {
          // console.log('return?');
          return;
        }
      }
    });

    dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(licence => {
      if (licence) {
        this._value.push(licence);
        this.dataSource.data = this.value;
        this.change();
      }
    });
  }
```

What is the best and optimized way to unsubscribe `beforeClosed()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from your description, I understand that you don`t want a second subscription to happen if the condition in the first subscriber is true, right? But you subscription will happen anyway because you instantiated it in the method, the code in the subscribe() it's just a callback. So if you don`t want a lot of rewriting I will suggest storing
subscriptions in variables, so you will have an access to them and can unsubscribe at any time.

```
openCreateNewContentDialog(): void {
const oldData = this.dataSource.data;
const dialogConfig = AppConstants.matDialogConfig();
const dialog = this.dialog.open(LicenseDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

const beforeClosed = dialog.beforeClosed().subscribe(licenceDate => {
  for (const datesToCheck of oldData) {
    const newDateFrom = new Date(licenceDate.expirationDateFrom);
    const oldDateTo = new Date(datesToCheck.expirationDateTo.toString());
    if (newDateFrom <= oldDateTo) {
      // console.log('return?');
      afterClosed.unsubscribe();
      return;
    }
  }
});

const afterClosed = dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(licence => {
  if (licence) {
    this._value.push(licence);
    this.dataSource.data = this.value;
    this.change();
  }
});
```

}

I hope it helps! Also you can try https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe if you have to handle multiple subscriptions.